# Stuck on a PHP If Statement

Tags: php, if-statement

Struggling to  code what should be a fairly simple if/else-type statement in PHP.  We have a lengthy web form that collects a sport's teams roster (with name, grade and date of birth for each youth player) and then sends that data back to the league's commissioner to be archived for future reference.

I set this form up more than a year ago and it's been working just fine.  However, I'd like to tweak it a bit to verify that all of the fields have been completed before executing the script (in case of user error).  Here is the code I'm trying to make work:

```
//Validate player 1:
if (!empty($_POST['player1'])) {
    $player1 = $_POST['player1'];
    $player1_dob = $_POST['player1_dob'];
    $player1_grade = $_POST['player1_grade'];
} elseif (!empty($_POST['player1_dob'])) {
    echo "You forgot to enter Player 1's date of birth.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} elseif (!empty($_POST['player1_grade'])) {
    echo "You forgot to enter Player 1's grade.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} else {
    $validate = 'true';
}
```

This seems like the most logical way (to me) to code the statement. However, the script is not verifying the date of birth and grade as intended.  Clearly, I am missing an important concept and not using the if/elseif correctly.  Perhaps a kind user can help point me in the right direction?

Comment: `!empty()` vs `empty()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `empty` vs. `!empty` is part of it. But also you need to check the pieces BEFORE you say "everything OK". Essentially flip it:

```
//Validate player 1:
if (!empty($_POST['player1'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['player1_dob'])) {
        echo "You forgot to enter Player 1's date of birth.<br>";
        $validate = 'false';
    } elseif (empty($_POST['player1_grade'])) {
        echo "You forgot to enter Player 1's grade.<br>";
        $validate = 'false';
    } else {
        $player1 = $_POST['player1'];
        $player1_dob = $_POST['player1_dob'];
        $player1_grade = $_POST['player1_grade'];
        $validate = 'true';
    }
}
```

It isn't clear from your code what you want to do if empty(player1) - i.e., fail validation or just skip the entire section, but either one can be handled easily.

Comment: Change the last `};` to `}`

Comment: @manassehkatz - This really helped the most because it showed me to how to properly nest if statements within if statements, which is what I was needing to do all along.  This was the "aha" moment.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would totally refactor what you are doing, but if you want to make it work, you have to remove `!` from the `elseif` statments. You are saying `if is not empty player 1 date of birth, error`, so here I think you wanted to say `if IS empty`.

Comment: Oops.  You guys are totally right.  I'm an idiot.  Thank you for the fresh set out of eyes.  Out of curiosity, what are you referencing by "refactor"?  Thanks, again!

Comment: In practice, it means "remake it differently".

Comment: No problem. I am saying that it is not good the way you are doing that, you are saying: If player1 data is not empty I will save all data, and if is empty, I will analyze each. But if player1_dob is empty, but not player1, you are saving an empty data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also isset function

```
$validate=true;
if (!empty($_POST['player1'])) {
    $player1 = $_POST['player1'];
    $player1_dob = $_POST['player1_dob'];
    $player1_grade = $_POST['player1_grade'];
 } 
if(!isset($player1_dob)) {
    echo "You forgot to enter Player 1's date of birth.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
 } 
 if (!isset($player1_grade))  {
    echo "You forgot to enter Player 1's grade.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
  }
  if($validation) {.... }
```